# intellitracesc.exe not running on XP

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run the intellitracesc.exe utility that allows for the collection of trace log info without needing VS 2012. We need to collect it for a VS 2010 application running on mostly xp boxes with .NET 3.5 on them. It has virtually impossible to reproduce some bugs, so hoping this would shed more light on it.

I downloaded and installed intellitracesc from here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245688.  When I run it I get "Intellitrace.exe is not a valid win32 application". If I run it on a machine with .NET 4.5, it runs fine.. is this the only issue? Not a ton of documentation out there on this utility..

Thanks
Harold

Answer (score 2):

There is the information at System Requirements by your [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245688):

> Supported Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008(x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
> - Windows Server 2012 (x64)

Windows XP is not supported.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh398365.aspx#BKMK_View_IntelliTrace_Log_Files) is the documentation for using.